# Where is Universal Windows Platform (UMP) for JavaScript within Visual Studio 2019 Community?

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

On the page: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/universal-windows-platform/
Microsoft describes C++, C#, VB, JavaScript for Blank App (Windows Universal). I had installed every significant component associated with it. .NET Framework 4.5.2, all ASP.NET features, web development tools, Visual Studio SDK (for extended templates) and I could find it for C++, C#, and VB but no JavaScript. I remember a similar thing happened with 2017 and I had just copied over the template from 2015. I no longer have the 2015 nor do I know if it is compatible.
Does anyone know where I can obtain the JavaScript for Blank App (Windows Universal) for Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 1):

I had found a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/400513/please-dont-remove-javascript-uwp-development-from.html) to put JS UWP back in VS 2019 here and Microsoft had discontinued UWP in the [Visual Studio Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2019?view=vs-2019).

I see Microsoft's logic since they had added Android and Apple support via Xamarin with C#. If you plan to do porting to multiple platforms that is how you would do closer to native.

For the rest of us who already started our apps with JS, it looks like we're going to have to migrate it to a PWA. Included are resources to get started.

[Getting Started with Progressive Web Apps with Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/getting-started-pwa)

[Getting Started with Progressive Web Apps with Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/get-started)